# Encrypt a file using KMS and push to S3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-kms

I have a AWS lambda function written in Python that needs to create a file using data in a string variable , KMS encrypt the file and push the file to S3.

```
s3_resource = boto3.resource("s3")
s3_resource.Bucket(bucket_name).put_object(Key=s3_path, Body=data)
```

I am using the above to create the file in S3 , but is there a way to use the KMS keys that I have to encrypt the file while pushing to S3 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use KMS encryption when adding an object use the [server side encryption](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Bucket.put_object) options:

- `ServerSideEncryption ="aws:kms"` - to enable KMS encryption
- `SSEKMSKeyId=keyId` - to specify the KMS key you want to use for encryption. If you don't specify this, AWS will just use your default account key.

For example:

```
s3_resource.Bucket(bucket_name).put_object(
        Key=s3_path,
        Body=data,
        ServerSideEncryption ="aws:kms"
    )
```

You may also need to [enable v4 signing](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingAWSSDK.html#specify-signature-version) in your boto configuration file.

Comment: Thanks @thomasmichaelwallace! The bucket is in a different account and they have enabled AES encryption. Can I still use this option to KMS encrypt the file and push it to the bucket?

Comment: Should I provide the KMS key arn for SSEKMSKeyId field?

Comment: Yes- the SSEKMSKeyId field should be the ARN. Although you will need to make sure you have the permissions all setup correctly (take a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48317364/how-do-i-get-aws-cross-account-kms-keys-to-work)

Comment: I see this error "An error occurred (InvalidArgument) when calling the PutObject operation: Multiple server side encryption methods are specified, only one method is allowed". Is it because the default encryption of the bucket is aes-256 and I am trying to send KMS as SSECustomerAlgorithm?

Comment: Sorry- some bad copy and pasting from the service definition there, I've updated the answer, you should be using ServerSideEncryption, not SSECustomerAlgorithm.

Comment: No worries. Sorry about the confusion!

Comment: If you pass just the ID to SSEKMSKeyId it will be resolved to proper arn